# как поменять местами кнопку и картинку в css не меняя их порядок в разметке html?

Tags: html, css

картинка и кнопка расположены вертикально. пробовал "order" не получилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для того чтобы ордер сработал родительский элемент должен быть `display: flex` или `display: inline-flex;`

```css
*,
html,
body {
    font-family:"Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.block-item {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.block-text.order2 {
    order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks">
    <div class="block-item">
        <p class="block-text">TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
        <button class="block-btn">button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="block-item">
        <p class="block-text order2">TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
        <button class="block-btn">button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, но к сожалению все равно не получилось поменять местами((

Comment: покажите код, я помогу поменять местами

Comment: https://codepen.io/aimakhansaken/pen/mdpMJZa

Comment: ок, где тут картинка и где тут кнопка? что надо менять местами?

Comment: ой простите не то отправил))

Comment: https://codepen.io/aimakhansaken/pen/mdpMJZa

Comment: https://codepen.io/eugene-kul/pen/KKZyrgO

Comment: вы `display: flex` добавили не на тот элемент

Comment: Сердешно благодарю))

Comment: не за что, отметьте, пожалуйста мой ответ, как решение вопроса, мне за это баллы дадут)